# Player changes size after external SWF is just loaded (but not used)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash player I am working on (developing in AS3).

The stage (and player) size are 640x979.

At the bottom of the player I have a control-bar, with play-pause buttons etc.

Here is an image of the player ([image](https://s14.postimage.org/ggi0pn7jj/good_banner_blurred.png)).

[image]

**So far so good.**

Now - on most external SWFs that I load - they load OK.
But on some - if I try to load them using the Loader class - the player goes crazy !
The control bar dissappears, and the video is stretched in a funky way. You can see this in the attached image ([image](https://s17.postimage.org/y6793x8zx/bad_banner_blurred.png)).

[image]

What is really strange here is - this happens even if I don't add the Loader object as a child !

I just do this :

```
public function PlayerCtor()
{
    swfUrlLoader = new Loader();
    swfUrlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfReceived);   
    swfUrlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSwfIOError);
    swfUrlLoader.load(new URLRequest(swfUrl));
}
private function onSwfReceived(e:Event):void
{
   swfUrlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfReceived);
   swfUrlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onSwfIOError);
}
```

.

That's it ! I don't do anything else besides just loading the external SWF !

The only things that I can think about are:

1. maybe the 'bad' SWF files have some code-behind in them that causes this behavior to happen ?
2. the 'bad' banners are supposed to be 906x340. I have noticed that
   they have animations flying in from 'outside' those boundries ... (I
   found this out by decompiling the SWFs using 'Flash Decomplier'
   trial).

Here are the SWF banners that are OK and don't do any problems:

- [Adom-Adom SWF](http://www.tnuva.co.il/PublishingImages/Banners/new_adom.swf)
- [Mama Off SWF](http://www.tnuva.co.il/PublishingImages/Banners/Mama_of.swf)

Here are the 'bad' banners that make my player go crazy:

- [Cheese SWF](http://www.tnuva.co.il/PublishingImages/Banners/Tnuva_TAMI_906x340.swf)
- [Emek Cheese SWF](http://www.tnuva.co.il/PublishingImages/Banners/New_emek_906x340.swf)

Can anyone help me figure out how to prevent this from screwing up my player, please ?

Thank you for everyone who can help !

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like some of the secondary loads are changing the stageAlign and/or the stageScaleMode.  see if changing stage.stageAlign and stage.stageScaleMode to the values you expect after the load is complete fixes the problem